# Empty array when filter inside deep an object

Tags: javascript

I made this function to filter in deep an array of object, but at the end the result is empty. If i check with console.log inside the if statement , it show me filtered object, but resultPost return me empty value. I also tryed to push inside an empty array the filtered value, but not work.

```js
const post = [{
    "name": "new post",
    "description": "simple desc",
    "taxonomies": {
      "categories": {
        "0": {
          "term_id": 15
        },
        "1": {
          "term_id": 20
        },
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "new post 2",
    "description": "simple desc 2",
    "taxonomies": {
      "categories": {
        "0": {
          "term_id": 11
        },
        "1": {
          "term_id": 12
        },
      }
    }
  }
];

const filterID = [15, 1];

const resultPost = post.filter(post => {
  if ((post.taxonomies.categories.filter(postct => postct.term_id === filterID)).length > 0) return post
});

console.log(resultPost);
```

Comment: `taxonomies.categories` is an object, you can't apply `filter` on object.

Comment: I turned your code into a snippet. When you run it, it produces the expected error on `filter` (as gorak explained). So it is not like you describe in your question.

Comment: what is your wanted output?

Comment: Yes you are right, i need the filtered post by id ( entire Object ) if categories match the filter. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter the posts by matching the `taxonomies.categories[id].term_id` as follows:

```js
    const post = [{
    "name": "new post",
    "description": "simple desc",
    "taxonomies": {
        "categories" : {
          "0" : {
            "term_id" : 15
          },
          "1" : {
            "term_id" : 20
          },        
        }
      }
    },
  {
  "name": "new post 2",
  "description": "simple desc 2",
  "taxonomies": {
      "categories" : {
        "0" : {
          "term_id" : 11
        },
        "1" : {
          "term_id" : 12
        },        
      }
    }
  }];

  const filterID = [15,1];

  const resultPost = post.filter(item => {
     const { categories } = item.taxonomies;
     return Object.keys(categories).reduce((cats, id) => {
    
     filterID.includes(categories[id].term_id) && cats.push(id);
     return cats;
     }, []).length
  });

  console.log( resultPost)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like said in comments, you can't use filter on an Object.
Try this instead

```
const resultPost = post.filter(post => {
    for (let cat in post.taxonomies.categories) { // one way to loop over objects
        // filterId is an array so you can't just use ===
        if (filterID.includes(post.taxonomies.categories[cat].term_id)) return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside filter, you can take `Object.values` of that object and then use `some` based on your condition to filter out records. Something like this:

```js
const post = [{ "name": "new post", "description": "simple desc", "taxonomies": { "categories": { "0": { "term_id": 15 }, "1": { "term_id": 20 }, } } }, { "name": "new post 2", "description": "simple desc 2", "taxonomies": { "categories": { "0": { "term_id": 11 }, "1": { "term_id": 12 }, } } }];

const filterID = [15,1];

const result = post.filter(p=>Object.values(p.taxonomies.categories).some(n=>filterID.includes(n.term_id)));

console.log(result);
```